# How to collect values in a for loop?

Tags: r

I want to collect all those individual which satisfy certain conditions in a matrix or data frame.

Here, id 222 and 333 in the end I am trying to get them in a matrix\dataframe within for loop.

How can I store these IDs in a data frame or matrix? I have hundereds of such ids:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333),
                     Amount = c(1,2,3,2,11,12,5,16,14))
    
for (i in unique(df$id)) {
    data <- df[df$id==i,]
    Amount_sum <- ifelse(data$Amount>10,1,0)
    if(sum(Amount_sum)>1) {
      print(data$id[1])
    }
}
```

Comment: `unique(df[df$Amount>10,"id"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `for` loop anyway, you can try the code below

```
out <- c()
for (i in unique(df$id)) {
  data <- df[df$id == i, ]
  if (any(data$Amount > 10)) {
    out <- c(out, i)
  }
}
```

and you will see

```
> out
[1] 222 333
```

---

Below are some other base R options, using `subset` + `aggregate`

```
> subset(aggregate(. ~ id, df, max), Amount > 10, select = id)
   id
2 222
3 333
```

or

```
> subset(aggregate(. ~ id, df, max), Amount > 10)$id
[1] 222 333
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the logic you were applying, you can easily concatenate the results, like this:

```
outo <- c()
df <- data.frame(id = c(111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333),
                 Amount = c(1,2,3,2,11,12,5,16,14))

# for loop to capture those IDs

for (i in unique(df$id)){
   data <- df[df$id==i,]
   Amount_sum <- ifelse(data$Amount>10,1,0)
   if(sum(Amount_sum)>1){
       outo <- c(outo,data$id[1])

}
}

outo
```

[1] 222 333